# Godot 4 ToSignal string parameter in C# for await

Tags: c#, async-await, gdscript, godot4

I am trying to create an interaction and dialogue system in Godot 4 using C#. Using the interaction system, I want to interact with an NPC which will trigger quest dialogue. The dialogue system seems to be working fine, but i am running into issues regarding the interaction system using async/await. Here is the code:

```
public async override void _Input(InputEvent @event)
{
    if (@event.IsActionReleased("Interact") && canIneract && activeAreas.Count > 0)
    {
        canIneract = false;
        interactDisplay.Hide();
        var result = activeAreas[0].Interact.Call(otherBody);
        await ToSignal((GodotObject)result, "DialogueComplete");

        canIneract = true;
    }
}
```

I am translating GDSript code from a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ajCraxGAeYU?si=p8XV5OBvjPvjCZJt&t=450) I am watching, and their code looks like this:

```
func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("interact") && can_interact:
        if active_areas.size() > 0:
            can_interact = false
            label.hide()

            await active_areas[0].ineract.call()
            can_interact = true
```

There is slight variation from my code to his, but the `await` line is what matters. I am trying to `await` on my interaction system until my dialogue system finishes. However, in C#, I have to use the ToSignal method in order to await like you see in the first example. I am a bit confused because the way you implement the same actions in GDScript can be very deferent from the C# version. I have tried to look online for a solution and to read the documentation, and the only hint that I got is to use the ToSignal method, and pass in the signal name that I want. But I keep getting this error.

```
E 0:00:05:0142   Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.generated.cs:108 @ Godot.Error Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.godotsharp_internal_signal_awaiter_connect(IntPtr , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , IntPtr , IntPtr ): Parameter "p_source" is null.
  <C++ Source>   modules/mono/signal_awaiter_utils.cpp:37 @ gd_mono_connect_signal_awaiter()
  <Stack Trace>  Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.generated.cs:108 @ Godot.Error Godot.NativeInterop.NativeFuncs.godotsharp_internal_signal_awaiter_connect(IntPtr , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , IntPtr , IntPtr )
                 SignalAwaiter.cs:18 @ Godot.SignalAwaiter..ctor(Godot.GodotObject , Godot.StringName , Godot.GodotObject )
                 GodotObject.base.cs:174 @ Godot.SignalAwaiter Godot.GodotObject.ToSignal(Godot.GodotObject , Godot.StringName )
                 InteractionManager.cs:88 @ void InteractionManager+<_Input>d__15.MoveNext()
                 :0 @ void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<TStateMachine >(TStateMachine& )
                 :0 @ void InteractionManager._Input(Godot.InputEvent )
                 Node.cs:2075 @ Boolean Godot.Node.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant& )
                 CanvasItem.cs:1374 @ Boolean Godot.CanvasItem.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant& )
                 Node2D.cs:516 @ Boolean Godot.Node2D.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant& )
                 InteractionManager_ScriptMethods.generated.cs:66 @ Boolean InteractionManager.InvokeGodotClassMethod(Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name& , Godot.NativeInterop.NativeVariantPtrArgs , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant& )
                 CSharpInstanceBridge.cs:24 @ Godot.NativeInterop.godot_bool Godot.Bridge.CSharpInstanceBridge.Call(IntPtr , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_string_name* , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant** , Int32 , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant_call_error* , Godot.NativeInterop.godot_variant* )
```

I dont know if my signal name is correct, and I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. The Signal I am referenceing is from my dialogue manager called DialogueManagerEventHandler, but apparently DialogueManager is not the signal name.

At this point, I dont know if I am going in the right direction, if what I am looking for just simply is not implemented in the C# API, or maybe if I am making a simple spelling error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be using `await` for a coroutine instead of a signal (notice that what they are passing to `await` is not a signal).

The way it works behind the scenes is that when the GDScript reaches an `await` it returns a `GDScriptFunctionState`, which encodes the position on the script to resume, and is scheduled for continuation. On the caller side, `await` will resume on the `completed` signal of the `GDScriptFunctionState`.

<strike>So, assuming this works from C#, try the `completed` signal.</strike> *Apparently it does not work.*

---

Anyway, if you are implementing this fully in C#, I'd say work with `Func<T, Task>` or similar instead of `Callable`.

In fact, C# tasks works on similar ideas※... If you write an `async` method in C#, the compiler will rewrite it as a series of continuations. When executing the code, the first block returns a `Task`, and schedules the next continuation, when the final continuation finishes it sets the `Task` completed.

※: [Who did async/await first?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/377514/45814)

---

**Addendum based on comments**

> I am looking for is waiting for a particular signal to trigger so the code can then continue on

You already know how to await for a signal: you use `ToSignal`.

Yet, this is not awaiting on a signal:

```
await active_areas[0].ineract.call()
```

In GDScript `await` has two use cases: it can await on a signal, or a coroutine. And this seems to be the latter. See [Awaiting for signals or coroutines](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#awaiting-for-signals-or-coroutines).

On the other hand, your code in C# is awaiting a signal from the object returned by calling `Interact`:

```
var result = activeAreas[0].Interact.Call(otherBody);
await ToSignal((GodotObject)result, "DialogueComplete");
```

Thus... The code that `Interact` points to needs to return an object that emits that particular signal.

Notice that if you emit the signal before returning from whatever `Interact` calls, the code that calls it (the one shown above) won't be awaiting the signal yet (because the code has not returned yet).

So, to be clear: the signal must be emitted by the object returned by `Interact` *AFTER* `Interact` returns it.

*One work around would be use to a deferred call inside the code pointed by `Interact` to emit the signal.*

---

> I should also mention that not only am I trying to wait until a particular task is completed, but that task calls other methods, some of which have to be activated with input.

You can have an object that handles input and emits a signal, and then you await on that signal.

Comment: I tried the completed signal, but that doesn't  work either. As for using async functions, I dont know much about them, but whenever I try reading or watching videos about them, it only tells me how to run the code asynchronously, but I am looking for is waiting for a particular signal to trigger so the code can then continue on. Everything I look at tells me to pause a function using await is to use Wait in milliseconds on a task. At this point, I am so lost that I have no idea if what I am saying makes sense. Do you know any good resources that I can learn from to understand async/await?

Comment: I should also mention that not only am I trying to wait until a particular task is completed, but that task calls other methods, some of which have to be activated with input.

Comment: @ShaneAmare I have updated the answer. By the way, aside from the official documentation, and searching on this side, I don't know what to recommend to understand async/await.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! I've been working on this stupid thing for days and tried everything! Thank you so much for the help and keep doing what you do!